# How to reduce the time cost while looping in a 4 million array in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I need to do the ‘vlookup’ function using the VBA. I need to lookup data from a access database containg 4.6 million records.

```
Private Sub connectDB()
 Dim sqlstr As String
 Dim mydata As String
 Dim t, d, conn, rst, mydata
 Dim arr, arr1
 t = Timer
 Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 mydata = "mydatabase"
 strconn = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source = " & mydata
 sqlstr = "select Tracking, MAWB from total"
 rst.Open sqlstr, strconn, 3, 2
 arr1 = Array("Tracking", "MAWB")
 arr = rst.GetRows(-1, 1, arr1)
STOP
#Above cost 1mins
 For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
    d(arr(0, i)) = arr(1, i)
Next
STOP
#Put data into dictionary always costs me 20 mins
```

The procedure above always cost me around 20 mins. And the majority of them are spent on the putting data into dictionary

Anyway to reduce the time cost?

Comment: If it is in access, why not use SQL to query?

Comment: Maybe try  `adOpenForwardOnly` for the cursor type and `adLockReadOnly` for lock type?  Scott's question is relevant though - how many lookups are you going to make against the data?

Comment: @ScottCraner Because I have to look up data for other multiple workbooks. I can't upload all the excel in access and to do the query

Comment: @TimWilliams About 1 million. But they are in different sheets and books. The majority time is spent on building the dictionary.

Comment: How about just bringing in the data that meets your criteria with a `Where` clause.

Comment: first of all this line `arr = rst.GetRows(-1, 1, arr1)` does not make sense, you only have 2 columns and when you create the recordset, just dump the recordset into the array simply with `arr = rst.GetRows`. Secondly, you are using late biding by defining the dictionary with create object. Late bindings are always slower than early bindings, so in the Tools/Reference check the scriptiong dictionary and simply create the dictionary with `dim d=new dictionary`. Thirdly, why do you want to create a dictionary of 4.5 million records?

Comment: I am not sure that dictionary will be fast when you are calling to get an item from it, plus, are you sure that you want to retrieve all of 4.5 million from the dictionary? that means you will burn more time again when calling it. So I would actually use the array to retrieve the data. I think you need to add some columns to the query such as ID etc so it can give you more power when looking up your specific value. You would use those extra columns as an index, if you needed sorting, do it in the SQL query level so it will be a lot faster than sorting the array.

Comment: You can easily come up with a function that finds your specific value from the array

Comment: The dictionary lookup will be fast - it's optimized for that, and the overhead to load it will probably be less than the time taken to run a million lookups (or to push a million values into the DB for a join).  I would maybe try skipping the getrows and run a loop directly on the recordset to load the dictionary.  4 million records is a lot of data though, so it's probably never going to be fast to fill.

Comment: @Ibo I don't know anyway to lookup a specific data in a array. Besides, I have 1m data to lookup from 4.6m...And 1m are in different excel files. I think upload 1m into database will take me more than 20 mins.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried to use recordset(Movenext loop). Its much more slower. Now i think there is no way to solve this...

Comment: We need to know more about the logic that will do the lookup. ACCESS compare to SQL Server or similar technologies is slow, but it will not take 20 minutes. That 20 mins that you are mentioning is not ACCESS, it is VBA

Comment: @Ibo Yes you are right..

Comment: Quite honestly, I would not try to do anything with 4.6 million rows in either Excel or Access. Do you have access to SQL Server? I would put the data into SQL and design a query to do what you're looking for.

Comment: He does not need to insert the 4.5 million in the Excel, he would just use VBA to shortlist what he wants and then paste it.

Comment: @PatJones Nah. The problem is I have excel files to lookup and the output should be the same excel files with an additional columns containing what i need.I think maybe the time spent on pushing excel to SQL server or something else and exporting them out to excel will be more...

Comment: Looping thru a recordset is terrible. for the number of records that you are saying, the best option is arrays. There is actually some good articles that demonstrate that so you know the direction, you just need to be creative to see what you want to pick from the array. Again, if you mentioned your conditions that makes a record a match, we could help

Comment: if you mean that you literally need to use LOOKUP function of Excel afterward it will be a terrible idea. Such functions will work for a certain maximum data size, the number that you are mentioning is big and you should never use any formula in that excel file. Only VBA and buttons for lookup

Comment: @Ibo Of course I mean using VBA...

Comment: It may be beneficial if you install PowerPivot and set it up to connect [Access database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413478(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm interested to see how vlookup performs after your 20min dictionary is created. 1Mio calls to your second function to check the dictionary will surely take some more time. I'm interested in the "final" time cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reduce significantly the lookup time by implementing your own [hashtable/dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Here's an example indexing a 4 millions array under 5 seconds:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RtlComputeCrc32 Lib "ntdll.dll" ( _
  ByVal start As Long, ByVal data As LongPtr, ByVal size As Long) As Long

Sub Example()
  Dim data(), slots() As Long, i As Long

  ' generate some records '

  ReDim data(0 To 1, 0 To 4000000)
  For i = 0 To UBound(data, 2)
    data(0, i) = CStr(i)
  Next

  ' index all the keys from column 1 '

  MapKeys slots, data, column:=0

  ' lookup a key in column 1 '

  i = IndexOfKey(slots, data, column:=0, key:="4876")

  If i >= 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Found at index " & i
  Else
    Debug.Print "Missing"
  End If

End Sub


Public Sub MapKeys(slots() As Long, data(), column As Long)
  Dim bucketsCount&, key$, r&, i&, s&, h&      
  bucketsCount = UBound(data, 2) * 0.9   ' n * load factor '
  ReDim slots(0 To UBound(data, 2) + bucketsCount)

  For r = 0 To UBound(data, 2) ' each record '
    key = data(column, r)
    h = RtlComputeCrc32(0, StrPtr(key), LenB(key)) And &H7FFFFFF  ' get hash '
    s = UBound(slots) - (h Mod bucketsCount)                      ' get slot '
    Do
      i = slots(s) - 1& ' get index (base 0) '

      If i >= 0& Then  ' if index for hash '
        If data(column, i) = data(column, r) Then Exit Do  ' if key present, handle next record '
      Else
        slots(s) = r + 1&  ' add index (base 1) '
        Exit Do
      End If

      s = i  ' collision, index points to the next slot '
    Loop
  Next
End Sub

Public Function IndexOfKey(slots() As Long, data(), column As Long, key As String) As Long
  Dim h&, s&, i&
  h = RtlComputeCrc32(0, StrPtr(key), LenB(key)) And &H7FFFFFF    ' get hash  '
  s = UBound(slots) - (h Mod (UBound(slots) - UBound(data, 2)))   ' get slot  '
  i = slots(s) - 1&                                               ' get index (base 0) '

  Do While i >= 0&
    If data(column, i) = key Then Exit Do  ' break if same key '
    i = slots(i) - 1&                      ' collision, index points to the next slot '
  Loop

  IndexOfKey = i
End Function
```

Comment: Congratulations, extremely fast (just 3,18 seconds).

Comment: @Tim Williams, it's a basic implementation of an [hashtable/dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which mimics the one from .Net. To keep it fast and short, it doesn't store the hash code and the chaining for the collisions is handled in the array holding the buckets.

Comment: I think your edited code is easier to follow - thanks for that. I will study up. I've always just reached for the scripting dictionary but with a lot of data it's not ideal and my answer above is nowhere near the approach you have here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer seems pretty good but its hard for to me to understand it...I'm just doing accounting job LOL

Comment: @Dingrui Zhang, If you don't feel comfortable tweaking this example, then have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/florentbr/75cbc2b9ea4cddea72383adaa6c09be4). You'll find a class named `JObject` which behaves more or less like `Dictionary`. Simply import the file and create the dictionary with `Dim dict As New JObject`, then set the capacity with `dict.SetCapacity 5000000`. It should be able to add and lookup 4000000 entries under 20 seconds.

Comment: @FlorentB. Thanks. After I imported the file ended with cls, some of the lines are red. They are "Version 1.0 Class" at the beginning and "Friend Sub x_load(dict As TFields)". It seems like VB code...I have no idea about them

Comment: @Dingrui Zhang, you need to import the file via `File > Import File` or by pressing Ctrl+M.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yes. I used ctrl+m to import the file. But they are still red.https://ibb.co/mi0HAG
https://ibb.co/hrk64b
https://ibb.co/eJyR4b

Comment: @Dingrui Zhang, in your capture the file was imported as a module. It needs to be a class module. Make sure that the file has the `.cls` extension.

Comment: @FlorentB. I'm pretty sure the file is cls extension. I'm using office 365 on Windows 7. https://ibb.co/hn7djb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160390/discussion-between-florent-b-and-dingrui-zhang).

Answer (score 4):

Although scripting dictionary is pretty fast at performing lookups, loading one up gets progressively slower the more you put into it: when you're in the millions of items then it gets really slow to load.

So, you could maybe consider something like splitting your values across an array of dictionary objects.  All other excellent suggestions aside, this would at least reduce your runtime with your current setup. The only caveat is the "keys" queried from your database would need to be unique.

```
Sub LookupTester()

    Const NUM_VALUES As Long = 4000000# '<< size of total dataset
    Const MAX_PER_DICT As Long = 400000 '<< max # of entries per dictionary

    Dim numDicts As Long, i As Long, n, t, d, v, r, c As Long
    Dim arrD() As Scripting.Dictionary

    numDicts = Application.Ceiling(NUM_VALUES / MAX_PER_DICT, 1)
    ReDim arrD(1 To numDicts)
    'initialize the array of dictionaries
    For n = 1 To numDicts
        Set arrD(n) = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Next n

    t = Timer
    n = 1
    c = 0
    Set d = arrD(n)

    'Load up some dummy data...
    For i = 1 To NUM_VALUES
        d("Value_" & i) = i
        c = c + 1
        If i Mod 400000 = 0 Then Debug.Print "Store", i, Timer - t 'check progresss
        If c = MAX_PER_DICT Then
            n = n + 1
            If i <> NUM_VALUES Then Set d = arrD(n)'<< next dict
            c = 0
        End If
    Next i
    'Done storing: 87 sec in my test


    t = Timer
    Randomize
    'perform a million lookups
    For i = 1 To 1000000#
        v = "Value_" & CLng(Rnd() * NUM_VALUES)
        For n = 1 To numDicts
            If arrD(n).Exists(v) Then
                r = arrD(n)(v) '<< lookup result
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
        If i Mod 100000 = 0 Then Debug.Print "Query", i, Timer - t
    Next i
    'Done querying: ~320 sec to run the queries

End Sub
```

You could wrap up this type of thing into a nice class...