# VBA Delete Duplicates code faster

Tags: vba, excel

Currently using this code, however, I have a huge set of data, and this runs really slow for that. I need to remove any duplicate information, and keep the highest row of information.

```
dim dup as variant, r as long, lncheckduplicatescolumn as long
With wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST)
     lncheckduplicatescolumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
     for r = lncheckduplicatescolumn  to 2 step -1
         dup = application.match(.cells(r, "A").value, .columns(1), 0)
             if dup < r then .rows(dup).delete
     next r
end with
```

Data:

```
       Column A              Column B
          A                      1
          B                      2
          C                      3
          A                      3
```

Result should be:

```
           B                     2
           C                     3
           A                     3
```

The order of data in column A doesnt matter as long as it is unique, and retains the information that is in the higher row number. While the code I shared works, it is too slow for a large data set.

Comment: So you never bothered to explore the efficiency increases derived by suspending calculation and event handling. What is the point of improving code that was handed to you when you never understood it in the first place?

Comment: same as your previous question .... describe what is happening in detail.  ....  what does this mean ? `I need to remove any duplicate information`  how do you decide when you have a duplicate?   ... we are getting tired of guessing.

Comment: @Jeeped i tried and tested the code but it takes a while. I used screen updating, calculations off etc but it still takes a while. While the code is great, I need a faster way since the data set is large. I understood the code, and tried to play around with it, but couldnt get it to work

Comment: @jsotola  I wanted the code to  look at cells values in column A, and if it finds a duplicate, delete the one that is in a lower row number. I will give an example above

Comment: Is data in two columns only or there are more columns? You can use an empty column to work out duplicates in one go and then delete it.

Comment: There are around 30-35 columns also, and when duplictae is found, I want the entire row to be deleted

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`

Comment: sort appropriately, then delete duplicates. That should run faster than your current code. recording a macro should help with the code needed

Comment: Tried, but doesnt work.

Comment: As you mention a *huge set of data* - could you define the number of data rows as well as an roughly approximated percentage of duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

Another fast method, is to use the `Dictionary` object. You can check if any of the values in Column A already exists in the `Dictionary`. If they do (meaning it's a duplicate), then don't delete them every time, this adds a long time for code's run-time. Instead, you can use a `DelRng` object, which is a `Range` that uses `Union` to merge multiple rows that are duplicates.

Later on, you can delete the entire ducplicates range at once by using `DelRng.Delete`.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicatesUsingDict()

Dim wb_DST As Workbook
Dim sWs_DST As String

'  Dictionary variables
Dim Dict As Object
Dim DictIndex As Long, ExistIndex As Long

Dim DelRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

' --- parameters for my internal testing ---
Set wb_DST = ThisWorkbook
sWs_DST = "Sheet1"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST)
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"

     For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not Dict.exists(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then ' value doesn't exists yet in Dictionary >> add this Key
            Dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, .Range("A" & i).Value
        Else ' value already exists in Dictionary >> add it to DelRng (later will delete the entire range)
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(i)) ' add current row to existing DelRng
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(i)
            End If
        End If
     Next i
End With

' delete the entire range at 1-shot
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. this eems to eb working a lot faster, i am still etsting it, and will keep u posted. Didn't even know about this functionality

Comment: Hi, this eems to be working however deletes the higher row of data. i need it to delete the lower row, so for example if row 2 and row 4 are duplicates, it should remove row 2

Comment: The code is removing data when it finds duplicate row, I just need to loop through column A to find duplicates and delete the row which is in a lower row number. As demonstrated above I want the A values from Row 4 instead of Row 1

Comment: @SM123 ok, try edited code (need to loop backwards if you wan to keep the value from the highest row)

Answer (score 1):

**Fast use of data field array**

Looping through a range isn't that fast - you can **speed it up considerably** if you create a data field array with your search data (array = needed range in column "A" - *see 1)* and loop therein. If your data set grows, this gets even faster in comparison to the above shown dictionary approach, though it rests a good and reliable method.

**Search Method**

- Any array value is checked against a concatenated search string with already found unique values and added if not yet included - *see 2)*
- The completed string is transformed to an array and written back to a given target column (e.g. "H") - *see 3) and 4)*

I even added a second column with the corresponding row numbers, so you should be in the position to use them for further action. You could write results to another sheet, too.

**Code - method demo**

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim t    As Double: t = Timer   ' stop watch
Dim ws   As Worksheet           ' source sheet (object)
Dim i    As Long                ' row index
Dim a, arr, arr2                ' variant
Dim s    As String, si As String
Const SEP = "|"                 ' delimiter
s = SEP: si = SEP
' 0) fully qualified range reference to source sheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' 1) write column A data to one based 2-dim data field array
  a = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
' 2) loop through data and check for duplicates in concatenated string s
  For i = 2 To UBound(a)
     If InStr(s, SEP & a(i, 1) & SEP) = 0 Then
        If Len(a(i, 1)) > 0 Then
           s = s & a(i, 1) & SEP
           si = si & i & SEP
        End If
     End If
  Next i
' 3) transform unique values to zero based 1-dim array
  arr = Split(Mid(s, 2), SEP)          ' duplicates string to array
  arr2 = Split(Mid(si, 2), SEP)        ' found row numbers
' 4) write result to column H2:H...      ' <<< change target to wanted column
  ws.Range("H:H").ClearContents         '
  ws.Range("H2:H" & (2 + UBound(arr))).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
  ws.Range("I2:I" & (2 + UBound(arr2))).Value = Application.Transpose(arr2)
  Debug.Print UBound(arr) + 0 & " unique items found", Format(Timer - t, "0.00 seconds needed")

End Sub
```

=================================================================

**EDIT**

**Version 2 -- includes overwriting original data with unique values**

Here you find a slightly modified version overwriting the original data in 35 columns (A2:AI..) with unique values.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates2()
' Edit: overwrite original data A2:AI{..} with unique values
Dim t    As Double: t = Timer   ' stop watch
Dim ws   As Worksheet           ' source sheet (object)
Dim i    As Long                ' row index
Dim a, arr, arr2                ' variant
Dim s    As String, si As String
Const SEP = "|"                 ' delimiter
Const MyLastColumn = "AI"       ' letter of last column (no 35) = "AI"
s = SEP: si = SEP
' fully qualified range reference to source sheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' write column A data to one based 2-dim data field array
  a = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
' loop through data and check for duplicates in concatenated string s
  For i = 2 To UBound(a)        '  For i = UBound(a) To 2 Step -1
     If InStr(s, SEP & a(i, 1) & SEP) = 0 Then
        If Len(Trim(a(i, 1))) > 0 Then
           s = s & a(i, 1) & SEP
           si = si & i & SEP
        End If
     End If
  Next i
' write unique values to zero based 1-dim array (starts with index 0; last delimiter removed in this version)
  arr2 = Split(Mid(si, 2, Len(si) - 2), SEP)     ' found row numbers
' overwrite original data      
  For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)  ' starts with index 0!
      s = "A" & arr2(i) & ":" & MyLastColumn & arr2(i)
      arr = ws.Range(s)        ' create 1-based 1-line (2-dim) array
      s = "A" & i + 2 & ":" & MyLastColumn & i + 2   ' 0 + 2 = +2 ... start in row 2
      ws.Range(s) = arr        ' write back unique row values
  Next i
  s = "A" & UBound(arr2) + 3 & ":" & MyLastColumn & UBound(a) + 1
  ws.Range(s).ClearContents     ' clear rest of original data
  Debug.Print UBound(arr2) + 1 & " unique items found", Format(Timer - t, "0.00 seconds needed")          ' result
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. i am testing it and will keep u posted

Comment: @T.M, string concatenation is expensive. You'll never beat a solution relying on a dictionary/hashtable given that your code has a complexity superior to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I added a 2nd version removing duplicate rows physically and hope this to be helpful. Using data field arrays is fast, but of course there are limits in concatenation (appreciate  @Florent-B 's hint), so I would like to know how many data rows you are using.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that @Florent-B recently posted a high level method showing a hash search over 4 million keys  at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584647/how-to-reduce-the-time-cost-while-looping-in-a-4-million-array-in-vba/47599207#47599207. - There are many ways leading to Rome (arrays, dictionary, even xmldom), depends on the actual situation.

Comment: a = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) this line gives an error saying Object required

Comment: This indicates that you didn't set the `ws` worksheet object correctly, e.g. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. (I tested code again and it worked without Problems)

Comment: @SM123, did you find where you set the worksheet object? Maybe it's nested within a condition that isn't executed.